# XML to SQL Server Insert

Tags: sql-server-2008, xml-parsing, openxml

I want to insert this XML data into SQL Server 2008

```
<rewriteMap name="OldStaticUrl">
   <add key="/about/" value="/about" />
   <add key="/2march2012" value="/community/0770/welcome-to-electronic-musicians-march-2012-links-page/147452" />
</rewriteMap>
```

I am using this SQL query

```
DECLARE @hdoc INT
DECLARE @doc varchar(1000)

SET @doc = '<rewriteMap name="OldStaticUrl">
               <add key="/about/" value="/about" />
               <add key="/2march2012" value="/community/0770/welcome-to-electronic-musicians-march-2012-links-page/147452" />
            </rewriteMap>'

 EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @doc

 SELECT vanity, originalurl
  FROM Openxml(@hdoc, '/rewriteMap/add',1) 
  WITH (vanity varchar(1000), originalurl varchar(1000))
```

But I am getting null in the result set, in fact if I use `select * from openxml`, I get multiple rows, some of which contains proper data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `vanity` and `originalurl` literals you should use `key` and `value` respectively.
Try this query:

```
DECLARE @hdoc INT
DECLARE @doc varchar(1000)
SET @doc = '<rewriteMap name="OldStaticUrl">
                <add key="/about/" value="/about" />
                <add key="/2march2012" value="/community/0770/welcome-to-electronic-musicians-march-2012-links-page/147452" />
            </rewriteMap>'
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @doc
SELECT [key], value
FROM Openxml( @hdoc, '/rewriteMap/add', 1) WITH ( [key] varchar(1000), value varchar(1000) )
```